# How to use MySQL and neo4j in single spring-boot application

Tags: mysql, neo4j, spring-boot

I have created application with spring-boot and neo4j. Following is spring boot application with neo4j

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "myproject" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "myproject")
public class Neo4jServer extends Neo4jConfiguration implements CommandLineRunner
{

  public Server()
  {
      setBasePackage("myproject");
  }

  @Bean
  SpringRestGraphDatabase graphDatabaseService()
  {
      return new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
  }

  public void run(String... args) throws Exception
  {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
      SpringApplication.run(Neo4jServer.class, args);
  }

}
```

AND following is **spring boot** application with mysql

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "myproject" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "myproject.persistence")
@PropertySource("myproject.properties")
public class MySQLServer extends DataSourceAutoConfiguration implements CommandLineRunner
{
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception
  {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    SpringApplication.run(MySQLServer.class, args);
  }

}
```

I have created properties file in resource package.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

So, There are now two application, one is with neo4j ie Neo4jServer.java and one is with MySQL ie MySQLServer.java
How to use both in single application.
Please make me correct if wrong.
Thank you :)

Comment: created properties file for mysql db properties. But didnt know what to further?

Comment: Check out http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Here is how you can use neo4j-jdbc in your boot application: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/developer-resources/tree/gh-pages/language-guides/java/spring-boot-jdbc

Comment: I have edited/added more to my question, may be it will give you idea what I have tried and want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to inject `MySQL` configured `DataSource`/`TransactionManager` bean to application class. `MySQL` `Entities`/`DAO` and `Neo4j` `Node`/`Relationship`/`DAO` needs to be in different packages. Then you can provide those respective packages for scan to `MySQL` and `Neo4j`.

Following code shows the configuration :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "myproject" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "myproject.persistence.mysql")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "myproject.persistence.neo4j")
public class Application extends Neo4jConfiguration
{
    @Autowired
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;

    public Application()
    {
        setBasePackage("myproject.persistence.neo4j");
    }

    @Bean
    SpringRestGraphDatabase graphDatabaseService()
    {
        return new SpringRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname");
        dataSource.setUsername("mysqluser");
        dataSource.setPassword("mysqlpassword");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() 
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("myproject.persistence.mysql");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.bytecode.provider", "javassist");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistence());
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager neo4jTransactionManager() throws Exception 
    {
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory.getObject()),
            new JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean(graphDatabaseService()).getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() 
    {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```